# New project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

So is there a way to create a new project in Android Studio without using the latest version of Android in the SDK? I know you can specify a minimum version of Android when creating a new project but there is no way to specify the target version or the compile version.

When the project is created and I then change the compile version and target version it complains about resources now no longer being recognised etc. What am I missing here?

Thanks,
Wihan

Comment: First of all it is possible: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html
but it's not needed. Then you should always target a latest one

Comment: I have already done this @Chaosit, but that is where the issue comes in.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, you can change values of `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. While, you need to do this in `build.gradle` in `Android Studio`.